# Mapping Stored Procedures to Complex Types in EF

Tags: entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a select of data with may joins, when I map it to EF, is creating a complex type model for that stored procedure. Can I change this complex type for another model class that has more columns that the stored procedure returns? or it has to return the same quantity of columns?

Thanks

For example, I have s stored procedure that returns a select of customers:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CustomersSelect]
AS

    SELECT [CustomerID]
          ,[CompanyName]
          ,[ContactName]
          ,[ContactTitle]
          ,[Address]
          ,[City]      
      FROM [Northwind].[dbo].[Customers]
```

I import this stored procedure in EF and instead of using a specific complex type, I would like to map it to the Customer class

```
public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            this.Orders = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public string CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
        public string ContactTitle { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string PostalCode { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Fax { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

In the controller I try to use this stored procedure:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
       var model = context.CustomersSelect();
       return View(model);
}
```

When I run this About() action, I receive this error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'EfMvc4Model.Customer'. A member of the type, 'Region', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

Any help for this?

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried? Can you show some example code of what you are trying to do?

Comment: I just want to know if the complex type defined has to be exactly the same as the result returned from the stored procedure.

Comment: I send a specific example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do what you're trying to do. If you have two separate stored procedures which returns two distinct sets of data (even if one is a superset of the other), you will need to use two separate complex types to map those stored procedures to.

As you've seen yourself: when you try to "re-use" the complex type for the second stored procedure (which returns fewer columns), you will run into an error something like this:

> System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException was unhandled
>
> The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'xxxxxxx'. A member of the type, 'ABC', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
>   Source=System.Data.Entity

and your second call will never work. I don't see how you could solve this - other than using **two** distinct, separate complex types that **exactly match** the output "shape" of your stored procedures.